# TTL field and IP checksum

Tags: tcp, udp, ip, checksum, ttl

If I change the **time-to-live** (TTL) field in an IP packet, should I also recompute the **IP checksum**?

And what about the checksum at the **transport layer** ? Will that have to change too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you change *any* field in the IP header, the checksum must be updated.

As for the checksum at the transport layer, it theoretically depends what the transport protocol is... however in practice I do not believe there exist any transport protocols whose checksums cover the IP TTL field. Certainly the pseudo headers for both TCP and UDP don't cover it.

Comment: OK. But routers also decrease the TTL value whenever they forward a packet. Do they also update the IP checksum each time?

Comment: Yes. Note that ethernet hardware often has the ability to calculate the IP checksum in hardware. The low-level code in routers and kernel IP stacks is normally able to coordinate with device drivers to make use of this functionality, saving the main CPU from having to do the work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you change the TTL field, then you have to change the checksum also because checksum is related to TTL field.

Also, TTL will be changed at every hop. Since TTL is changing at every hop, so checksum will also be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. According to RFC 791

> A checksum on the header only.  Since some header fields change (e.g., time to live), this is recomputed and verified at each point that the internet header is processed.